# How to transpose a "Measure" table in Power BI desktop?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am having a "Measure" table in PowerBI desktop which I want to transpose it in Query Editor, I know how to do this if it is not a measure or calculated table, any ideas how to achieve it with measure table?

Answer (score 0):

You can't go back with PowerPivot tables to PowerQuery. Your only option is to stay in PowerPivot and use DAX. Unfortunately there is no transpose function in DAX, so you basically have to construct your transposed table manually using the SELECTCOLUMNS() and FILTER() functions.

In the Packt library there is a recipe how to achieve that: [Transposing tables](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/data/9781839217074/12/ch12lvl1sec28/transposing-tables)

Depending on your data model it might be easier to create a transposed copy of your table in PQ before you start adding measures in PP.